# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined -- Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, javascript-objects

I would like to change the color, fontsize and font weight of the text in a span element of the html page.

I am using the following code:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("test") > -1){
    var search_span = document.getElementsByClassName("securitySearchQuery");
    search_span[0].style.color = "blue";
    search_span[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    search_span[0].style.fontSize = "40px";
}
```

Following is the code for my html page

```
<h1 class="keyword-title">Search results for<span class="securitySearchQuery"> "hi".</span></h1>
```

I thought of getting elements by id but unfortunately they only classes and no ids. I do not have access to change the html code but just to add js code to website externally.

I have tried to look into other stackoverflow posts but could find the solution.
Am new to js and css,Please let me know where am going wrong.

[image: This is the screenshot of the error which I am getting in Chrome browser]

Comment: This works when I try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/du2ot93e/ - I think your `if` statement is failing.

Comment: Do you reach the `if` statement?

Comment: That code works. Things you should look for: is there the if condition that you want? Are you reading the property 'style' in other place of your code? Is there where the code fails?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for replying. I have attached the screenshot of the image. When am using a Code snippet in Chrome developers tools and excluding if condition the code works well but when I add with if condition and I insert the code in actually system, then it gives this error its kind of weird for me

Comment: Sidenote: Since you are looking for a single element you could use `var span = document.querySelector(".securitySearchQuery");`, which returns a single element, and then just reference `span.style` without needing to select the `0` index.

Comment: Thanks a lot Useless Code (sorry i dont know ur name) .... I will that ... that really helped

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add your `<script>` to the bottom of your `<body>`, or add an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` following [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).

If that script executes in the `<head>` section of the code, `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` will return an empty array because the DOM is not loaded yet.

You're getting the `Type Error` because you're referencing `search_span[0]`, but `search_span[0]` is `undefined`.

This works when you execute it in Dev Tools because the DOM is already loaded.

Answer (score 6):

It's currently working, I've just changed the operator **`>`** in order to work in the snippet, take a look:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  if (window.location.href.indexOf("test") <= -1) {
    var search_span = document.getElementsByClassName("securitySearchQuery");
    search_span[0].style.color = "blue";
    search_span[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    search_span[0].style.fontSize = "40px";

  }

}
```

```html
<h1 class="keyword-title">Search results for<span class="securitySearchQuery"> "hi".</span></h1>
```